# How do the scores on this sports ticker update itself without ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I was looking at scores at http://www.cbssports.com/nfl/scoreboard earlier and upon inspection of the code, I couldn't quite figure out how they update their scores.

I don't see any ajax calls and the games don't appear to be wrapped into iframes, etc.

Can anyone explain to me how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like they are using Flash code to update the scores. I disabled Flash in my browser and got the following message:

[image: Live Scoring Notice]

However, if you want to implement something like that without using a Plugin, you can use [Websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Check out line 1884 of the `scoreboard` file. The `storePlayers` function will format that big string into sets of markup that is used in the ticker.